# HttpControllerContext.Configuration is sometimes null during Content negotiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

We are setting up a ASP.NET 4.6.2 Web Api host and noticing that some requests fail because of the following error:

```
HttpControllerContext.Configuration must not be null.
```

I've been unable to reproduce the issue and wanted to ask if anybody could steer me in the right direction?

This is the stack trace:

```
[0] System.InvalidOperationException "HttpControllerContext.Configuration must not be null."
   at System.Web.Http.Results.NegotiatedContentResult`1.ApiControllerDependencyProvider.EnsureResolved()
   at System.Web.Http.Results.NegotiatedContentResult`1.ApiControllerDependencyProvider.get_ContentNegotiator()
   at System.Web.Http.Results.BadRequestErrorMessageResult.Execute()
   at System.Web.Http.Results.BadRequestErrorMessageResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()
```

Comment: You code needs to wait until the entire response is returned.  Using Asynchronous methods often start processing before all the data is obtained which could account for the null.

Answer (score 4):

A similar error occurred in my tests when adding headers to a BadRequestErrorMessageResult. The fix only required to initialize the controller's Configuration.
...and subsequently initialize the Request.

So my test's setup ended up looking something like

```
public class FooControllerTest
{
    private FooController _sut;

    [Setup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _sut = new FooController();
        _sut.Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
        _sut.Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: For me, this returns InternalServerError. When I debug, it works correctly though.