# Controller test fails only on server

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ncrunch

So I built unit tests for an ApiController, and one of those fails only on the server in the CI pipeline with the exception `System.InvalidOperationException : HttpControllerContext.Configuration must not be null.`

The structure looks like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult MyControllerMethod()
{
  if(this.SomeThings()) // uses this.IService and this.IService2
    return this.UnAuthorized();

  DoOtherStuff();
  return this.Ok();
}
```

In my test, I mock IService and IService2 and pass them to the controller:

```
var controllerUnderTest = new MyController(serviceMock, serviceMock2);
```

Then I call the method with some invalid data, provoking the return of `UnAuthorized()`:

```
var result = await controllerUnderTest.MyControllerMethod(invalidData).ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);`
```

At first, this failed. So I added

```
controllerUnderTest.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
controllerUnderTest.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
```

from [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480264/httpcontrollercontext-configuration-is-sometimes-null-during-content-negotiation).

So now it works. Locally. It works when debugging, it works using ReSharper's testrunner, it works using NCrunch.

But it doesn't work in the pipeline.
When executed in the pipeline using ncrunch console tool, the tests fails with above message.

Any idea how to fix this? How can config be nul when I explicitely initialize it?

**Edit:** Here is the stacktrace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : HttpControllerContext.Configuration must not be null.
bei System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult.ApiControllerDependencyProvider.EnsureResolved()
bei System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult.ApiControllerDependencyProvider.get_IncludeErrorDetail()
bei System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult.Execute()
bei System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: _"How can config be nul when I explicitely initialize it?"_ - it shouldn't. Are you sure your pipeline is running on the most recent code?

Comment: I am - it runs each time I push changes. I tried it using object initializer or without that, setting nothing or setting only the request. It's a gitlab ci runner, it clones anew for every pipeline.